# Aligning a table transferred to cucumber from Excel

Tags: excel, windows, cucumber, notepad++, gherkin

I often need to transfer tables from Excel to cucumber.  I use Excel formulas to compute expected results for my data driven testing so it is natural to define those inputs in Excel.  My problem is that I need to separate Gherkin table columns with space-bar-space characters (" | ") and I need the bar characters to align. My current process gets me close but requires annoying manual touch up steps at the end that can take five minutes or more for large tables.  Can anyone suggest how to improve my process?

My current process is:

```
1. Place the table headers in row one of the Excel worksheet
2. Fill the data in each row under the headers
3. Select the headers and data in Excel and paste into a Notepad++ blank tab.  
   What follows takes place in Notepad++.
4. Using Extended search mode replace "\t" with " | " (omit the double quotes)
5. Using Extended search mode replace "\r\n" with " |\r\n" (omit the double quote)
6. Using Regular Expression search mode replace "^" with "\| " (omit the double quotes)
7. Copy a bar charcter ("|") to the clipboard
8. Select all then TextFX -> TextFX Edit -> Line up multiple lines by (Clipboard character)
9. Edit -> Blank Operations -> TAB to Space
```

What's left is close.  Some table cells lack a space before the separating bar character ("|"). Some cells have too many spaces after the separating bar character ("|").  I touch up columns using column mode and replace all. I would like to avoid the need for these manual steps.

I have searched the web and Stackoverflow but haven't found anything that addresses my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You should write a script in your favorite scripting languge.

Comment: @toto Your comment got me thinking,  So I changed my search parameters and found [Tidy Gherkin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tidy-gherkin/nobemmencanophcnicjhfhnjiimegjeo?hl=en-GB).  That did the trick nicely. Thank you.

Comment: @toto My work philosophy is to only get creative when innovation (i.e. apply existing solution to a new situation) fails.  Now when I am on my own time, that is a different story. :-)

Comment: If you need this frequently, you may also consider placing the excel files next to your feature files and using file name references and some library to retrieve the data straight from the excel files.